# JSON Unexpected Syntax error - Date parsing / encoding / decoding

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml-parsing

I convert a date to minus 1 day and in a format of YYYY-MM-DD .

Here is how I minus 1 day.

```
var date_to_selector         = $(this).parent().find("input[name=date_to]");
var date_to = date_to_selector.val();
    var last_night = new Date(date_to_selector.val().toString());
        last_night.setDate(last_night.getDate()-1);
    var last_night_date = last_night.toLocaleString("en-CA", {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).split("/").join("-");
```

When using this in a request, I get a SYNTAX Error where:

```
 Array
(
    [soapFault] => Array
        (
            [faultcode] => soap:Client
            [faultstring] => Unmarshalling Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'date'. 
        )

)
```

In browser debugging, I can see the correct date in the correct format however, when posting to URL, it sees $last_night_date as invalid JSON I assume?

Comment: The error message doesn't talk about JSON. Something should be a date but is an empty string.

Comment: And the error is also not a syntax error.

Comment: Which is the above, the section that should be a date isn’t being a date regardless of above

Comment: The stated error is from an XML parser - there is no JSON involved here. You need to change your WSDL for that field from `xsd:data` to `xsd:string`.

Comment: How can I set the above date YYYY-MM-DD to be in that format xsd:data?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe be because

1. Every bowser out there doesn't support every date format.
2. Mismatch in format support between browsers or client-server might result in errors.
3. Your request param parser is throwing an error because it doesn't understand your format

You should send the date after stringifying it and then parse it again.
If dealing with multi timezones then stringify it in ISO format.

Comment: Can you give an example for possibility 3? 

I previously did this at the backend using strototime - posted successfully but server responded with 500

Comment: With JS you can use "new Date("2021-11-21").toISOString()". Send it to server after changing it in ISO.

Comment: So it accepts only toISOString not toLocaleString?

Comment: _"maybe..."_ is not an answer. This should be a comment.